# Prove the function is a homomorphism and calculate the image

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the function $f: (Z_{10}, +_{10}) \to (Z_{20}, +_{20})$  defined by $f(n)=2n$. Show that $f$ is a homomorphism and calculate the image.

[NOTE: $Z_m = \{0,1,2,...,m-1\}$ is a group under the operation $+{_m}$ defined via $i +_m j$ equals the remainder of $i+j$ when divided by $m$.]

I understand that to prove homomorphism I need to show that the Homomorphic Property holds: $f(x*y)=f(x)*f(y)$. But I'm not entirely sure how to go about it using the $+_m$ notation. I also have no idea how to find the image, which is defined by $\{f(g)|g \in G\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y \in Z_{10}$ and say $x+y=z$ (within the additive group). Then, if we ignore the modulus and just consider the elements as integers, we have $x+y=z+t$ where $t$ is some multiple of $10$ (really, it'll just be either $0$ or $10$). Then $f(x)+f(y)=2(x+z)=2x+2y=2z+2t$, where this is without the modulus. With respect to the group, $f(z)=2z$. Can you see why these things, mod($20$), are equal?

EDIT: Also, with regard to the image, say $f(g)=h$ for $g \in Z_{10}, h \in Z_{20}$. What can you say is certainly true about $h$, no matter what $g$ is chosen?

Comment: Well... $h$ is the image... and the function is defined by $f(n)=2n$ so then $h=2g$...yes?

Comment: Right, so $2g$ is even, right? And if you subtract an even number from another even number (due to the modulus), you get...?

Comment: You get another even number...why are we subtracting?

Comment: Because you're taking it mod $20$, so you're subtracting $20$ or $0$. The point you need to take into account is that if you take an even number mod an odd number less than it, then the result is an odd number.

Comment: And if the result is an odd number then it is not in the image?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the result", but just consider any odd number in $Z_{20}$. Can you find any way to express it as a sum of an even number and an integer multiple of $20$?

Answer (score 0):

The homomorphism property is just  $f (x+y)=2 (x+y)=2x+2y=f (x)+f (y) $.

You can check that the kernel is  $\mathbb Z_2\cong\{0,5\} $, and,  by the first isomorphism theorem,  the image is isomorphic to  $\mathbb Z_{10}/\mathbb Z_2\cong\mathbb Z_5$.  It is the subgroup  $\{0,4,8,12,16\} $, the only  $\mathbb Z_5$ in $\mathbb Z_{20} $.